# Prove that N is a norm on $ℓ^3$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For each $z = (c_n)_{n≥1} ∈ℓ^3$, let
$$N(z) =\bigg( \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|c_n|^3}{|n|^3} \bigg)^{1/3}$$ Prove that N is a norm on $ℓ^3$. You may use without proof standard facts.

---

Sequences $(c_n)$ and $(1/n)$ are in $\ell^3$ so $\sum |c_n|^3$ and $\sum |1/n|^3$ are finite so by null sequence test $|c_n|^3, |1/n|^3 \rightarrow 0$ so $|c_n /n|^3 \rightarrow 0$.

Hence $\sum|c_n /n|^3 $ is finite so $N(z)$ is finite.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\in \ell^3$. That is, $\sum_n \vert c_n\vert^3<+\infty$. Since $\frac{\vert c_n\vert}{n}\leq\vert c_n\vert$ for all $n$, this implies $N(z)\leq\sum_n \vert c_n\vert^3<+\infty$. In other words, for each $z\in \ell^3$, the sequence $\bar z=\left( \frac{c_n}{n}\right)_n$, is in $\ell^3$ as well.

To see $N(z)$ is a norm:

- $N(z)=0\iff z=0$ is direct.
- Let $\lambda\geq0$. Let $\bar z=\left( \frac{c_n}{n}\right)_n$, which we already know is in $\ell^3$.Then $N(\lambda z)=\Vert \lambda \bar z\Vert_3=\lambda \Vert \bar z\Vert_3=\lambda N(z)$.
- To prove the triangle inequality, let $x=(x_n)_n$ and $y=(y_n)_n$ in $\ell ^3$. Let $\bar x=\left( \frac{x_n}{n}\right)_n$ and $\bar y=\left( \frac{y_n}{n}\right)_n$, which we also know are in $\ell^3$. By triangle inequality of the typical norm in $\ell^3$, 
  $$
  N(x+y)=\Vert \bar x+\bar y\Vert_3\leq \Vert \bar x\Vert_3+\Vert \bar y\Vert_3=N(x)+N(y)
  $$

Comment: Are $N$ and $||.||_3$ equivalent?

Comment: No. It is true that $N(x)\leq \Vert x\Vert_3$ for all $x$. However, there is no $C>0$ s.t. $\Vert x\Vert_3\leq C\cdot N(x)$ for all $x$. To see this, for each $C>0$, we can consider $x$ s.t. $x_{\lceil C\rceil}=1$ and $x_n=0$ otherwise.

Comment: could you elaborate on the sequence you gave please. I cant really understand it...

Comment: or could you please give a simpler example because this one is so confusing...

Comment: Sorry I was busy. To see that $N(\cdot)$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_3$ are not equivalent, we have to show that for all $C>0$, there is $z\in \ell^3$ s.t. $\Vert z \Vert_3>C\cdot N(z)$. One idea is this: let $C>0$, and let $k>C$, with $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider then the following $z=(c_n)_n\in \ell^3$:
$$
c_n=\begin{cases}
1 & n=k\\
0 & n\neq k
\end{cases}
$$
We have $N(z)=1/k$ and $\Vert z\Vert_3=1$. Hence $\Vert z \Vert_3=1>C/k=C\cdot N(z)$.

Comment: One last question, is there a way that you can easily see just by reading, if they are equivalent? Like how did you right away know that they were not?

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps my answer to this will be disappointing. The reason why I suspected quickly they were not equivalent, was because $\ell^3$ is infinite dimensional, and I find even infinite dimensional *Banach* spaces are really weird (for instance the closed unit ball is not compact in those spaces), so I think finding equivalent norms in those spaces is really difficult too (unless you multiply one norm by a non-zero constant).